# Convert Double into 8-bytes array

Tags: vb6

I want to convert a `Double` variable into an 8-bytes array, this is what I've come with so far:

```
Dim b(0 To 7) As Byte
Dim i As Integer

dim d as double
d = 1            ' for simplicity, I sit the variable "d" to 1

For i = 0 To 7
    Call CopyMemory(b(i), ByVal VarPtr(d) + i, 1)
Next i

' b => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 63]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a loop, use the length argument:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    ByRef Destination As Any, _
    ByRef Source As Any, _
    ByVal Length As Long)

Sub DblToByte(ByVal D As Double)
    Dim Bytes(LenB(D) - 1) As Byte
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim S As String

    CopyMemory Bytes(0), D, LenB(D)

    For I = 0 To UBound(Bytes)
        S = S & CStr(Bytes(I)) & " "
    Next
    MsgBox S
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    DblToByte 1
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: And an example of [how to convert back again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15782705/588306).

Answer (score 4):

You don't show your declare statement, but CopyMemory can be declared differently for different uses of it. Try:

```
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
                                                 ByVal pDst As Long, _
                                                 ByVal pSrc As Long, _
                                                 ByVal ByteLen As Long _
                                                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to this party, but we've had some code using CopyMemory that used to be lightening fast, then suddenly it has ground to a halt.  I believe this to be due to changes with Windows Defender.  I have a simple work around.  Create two types, one to hold a double, one to hold the 8 bytes that make up a double.  Then use the LSet function to copy the binary data from one to the other.  It runs 6000(!) times faster than CopyMemory.  Pretty rubbish that a native API call is now incredibly slow compared to VBA, but there we are...

```
Private Type TypeDoubleByte
  b1 As Byte
  b2 As Byte
  b3 As Byte
  b4 As Byte
  b5 As Byte
  b6 As Byte
  b7 As Byte
  b8 As Byte
End Type

Private Type TypeDouble
  d As Double
End Type

Private Sub WriteDouble(bytes() As Byte, ByRef pos As Long, val As Double)

  Dim t As TypeDoubleByte
  Dim z As TypeDouble

  z.d = val
  LSet t = z

  bytes(pos + 0) = t.b1
  bytes(pos + 1) = t.b2
  bytes(pos + 2) = t.b3
  bytes(pos + 3) = t.b4
  bytes(pos + 4) = t.b5
  bytes(pos + 5) = t.b6
  bytes(pos + 6) = t.b7
  bytes(pos + 7) = t.b8

  pos = pos + 8

End Sub
```