# VBA bit converter

Tags: vba, bitconverter

I would like to know how to use the bitconverter method in Excel VBA.
I would like to convert 4 bytes each one placed in a difference cells in a 32 bit integer using BitConverter.ToInt32.

Can someone help me with an example to use in VBA? I think I am struggling with the syntax.

Thanks

Comment: `I would like to convert 4 bytes to a 32 bit integer` and `I would like to convert 4 bytes to a 32 bit integer using BitConverter.ToInt32 in VBA` are [two different questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640). What do you want to do - find a way to call .NET's `BitConverter`'s methods from VBA or convert 4 bytes to an int in VBA?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My final goal is to to convert 4 bytes to an int in VBA. I thougth the most pratical would be calling .NET's BitConverter, but if there is another path I would also be glad to learn

Comment: If you want to call .NET's `BitConverter`, then lookup how to call .NET code from VBA, don't ask people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

- With `CopyMemory`:

  ```
  Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

  Public Function BytesToLong(b() As Byte) As Long
    CopyMemory BytesToLong, b(LBound(b)), 4
  End Function
  ```
- Without `CopyMemory` 1:

  ```
  Private Type thebytes
    b(1 To 4) As Byte
  End Type

  Private Type thelong
    l As Long
  End Type


  Public Function BytesToLong(b() As Byte) As Long
    Dim tb As thebytes, tl As thelong
    Dim lb As Long

    lb = LBound(b)
    tb.b(1) = b(lb)
    tb.b(2) = b(lb + 1)
    tb.b(3) = b(lb + 2)
    tb.b(4) = b(lb + 3)

    LSet tl = tb

    BytesToLong = tl.l
  End Function
  ```
- Without `CopyMemory` 2:

  ```
  Public Function BytesToLong(b() As Byte) As Long
    Dim lb As Long
    lb = LBound(b)

    If (b(lb + 3) And &H80) = &H80 Then
      BytesToLong = (b(lb) + b(lb + 1) * &H100& + b(lb + 2) * &H10000 + (b(lb + 3) And Not &H80) * &H1000000) Or &H80000000
    Else
      BytesToLong = b(lb) + b(lb + 1) * &H100& + b(lb + 2) * &H10000 + b(lb + 3) * &H1000000
    End If

  End Function
  ```

Comment: Nice spoonfeeder answer... would definitely upvote if it were a decent question.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I tried hard not to answer, but there appears to be no proper duplicates other than https://stackoverflow.com/q/7801080/11683 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/15782705/11683, so I thought, whatever. I have upvoted your comment.

Comment: eh, what the heck, have it anyway =)

Comment: thanks a lot GSerg! I am really a beginner in VBA so there are a lot of things that I still don't grasp, I apologise if the question sounded too silly  or too obvious, that was not my intention.