# how to convert int to float in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to convert a pair of integers into a floating point variable (they should translate in a float value). I succesfully converted the pair of integers into a Long and i assumed that I was homefree by using the CDbl function. Unfortunately I am just getting the same number in the Double variable. The Long has a number like 1141187758 and this should translate in something like 530.xxx as a float. Anybody who can help me with this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. A numerical value will be the same in any other numerical data type bar any rounding. Do you mean you are expecting it to look more like `1.14188888818776E+15`

Comment: Did you ask this same question on a forum 10 years ago or is this an assignment from some school? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?259885-Convert-Integer-to-Float

Comment: this question represent exactly what im searching for, but in this forum i cannot get the response , what i want is converting an int = 1121991000 to a float in my example the float will be = 112.112, you can refer to his website for more example : http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049049050046049049050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air code

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _ 
     ByRef Destination As Any, _ 
      ByRef Source As Any, _  
      ByVal Length As Long) 

Function LongToFloat(ByVal l As Long) as Single 
    Dim f As Single 
    CopyMemory f, l, LenB(l) 
    LongToFloat = f 
End Function
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801080/convert-double-into-8-bytes-array/7802141#7802141)

Comment: "Air code" as in "air guitar": I mean I just typed it straight into the answer. It may not even compile.